# How to properly reference a local, dependent derivation's output directory

Tags: nixpkgs

I have a derivation (`default.nix`) defined as:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
let
  version = "7.5.1";
in  
stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "gurobi-${version}";
  src = fetchurl {
    url = http://packages.gurobi.com/7.5/gurobi7.5.1_linux64.tar.gz;
    sha256 = "7f5c8b0c3d3600ab7a1898f43e238a9d9a32ac1206f2917fb60be9bbb76111b6";
  };
  installPhase = ''
    cp -R linux64 $out
    patchelf --set-interpreter \
      ${stdenv.glibc}/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 $out/bin/*
    patchelf --set-rpath ${stdenv.glibc}/lib $out/bin/*
  '';
  GUROBI_HOME = "$out";
}
```

Aside: even when I have `cp -R linux64 $out/`, it seems the contents of `linux64` are copied into `$out`, rather than `linux64` itself being copied into `$out` ... which seems non-standard, I think.

A second file (`gurobi-shell.nix`) is:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};
let
  myGurobi = (import ./default.nix);
in stdenv.mkDerivation  {
  name = "gurobi-shell";
  buildInputs = [ myGurobi ];
  shellHook = ''
   export GUROBI_HOME="${myGurobi.GUROBI_HOME}"
   export GUROBI_PATH="${myGurobi.GUROBI_HOME}"
  '';
}
```

When I run `nix-shell gurobi-shell.nix` and then `echo $GUROBI_HOME`, I get:
`/nix/store/jsy0q02hyprz6mllblfb0gim3l8077d8-gurobi-shell`

However, I expect and want it to be:
`/nix/store/s2kj78cnpnnbwr6q8qylg0n02m0sm32a-gurobi-7.5.1`

**EDIT**: I guess that this may have something to do with lazy evaluation, but am not sure. In any case, I found a workaround, which is to use `myGurobi.out` instead of `myGurobi.GUROBI_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, as an answer to your aside: when the `installPhase` is run, $out has not been created yet. If the destination does not exist, `cp` will copy the the directory `linux64` to create the directory named with the value of `$out`, and so the contents of `$out` will be the same as the contents of `linux64`.  You might want to `mkdir -p $out` at the beginning of your `installPhase` if you expect `$out` to exist as a directory.

For the main part of your question: `"$out"` in your `GUROBI_HOME` setting is setting `GUROBI_HOME` to the literal value `$out`, not to the expanded output path of the derivation. When you reference `${myGurobi.GUROBI_HOME}` in your `shellHook`, this is expanding to `export GUROBI_HOME="$out"`. Since nix-shell is expected to recreate the environment used when building the derivation, `$out` is set to the output directory of the `gurobi-shell` derivation, which is why you are getting it set to the wrong value.